# Accessing an Angular.JS controller's name property in JavaScript (why is it the module's name?)

Tags: angularjs

I have [some simple Angular.js code](http://jsfiddle.net/dumbledad/ufm064nd/) that I do not understand.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

var controller = myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
}]);

alert(controller.name);
```

The HTML directive produces what I would expect: "Hello, Superhero!" is rendered to the page. But the alert box is perplexing. I would expect it to show the string "Superhero", or perhaps the controller's name "MyCtrl", but what it actually shows is the module's name "MyApp". Why? What would I need to pass to `alert` to show the name assigned to the controller's scope (i.e. "Superhero") or the name of the controller itself (i.e. "MyCtrl")?

(N.B. I did try [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller) but it didn't help me untangle why the controller is reporting the module's name instead of its own.)

Comment: `myApp.controller()` returns the module so you can chain registration together

Comment: That makes sense of what's happening. How do I programmatically access the controller I just created? Plus where is the documentation foe myApp.controller()? [The documentation I was looking at](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller) suggests it returns the controller, but that's probably the wrong page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to access angular's code from a legacy code.

the way I do it is with angular.element:

```
<div id="myDiv" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
</div>   

var theScope = angular.element(getElementById('myDiv')).scope();
alert(theScope.name);
```

Comment: So in my code the way to get the controller I just created is to search the DOM for it? That'll work (thanks) but seems odd.

Comment: It's not that odd when you think of it this way - the dom element is the only one who can really behave as you wish because the controller itself can be used among many other dom elements @dumbledad

Comment: But isn't that exactly why you might want access to the controller itself?

Comment: I can't really tell because I'm not sure what is you intention when accessing it from legacy code. What I do know is that a single controller can be launched multiple times and than your 'name' scope variable has multiple values. only a DOM element that initiate the CTRL has a single value for name

Comment: That helps, thanks. I'm not sure what you mean by 'legacy code' (I usually parse that as code from a previous language, project, or version). What do you mean by 'legacy code' here?

Comment: Hoo sorry about that. legacy code mean pure javascript - out of every framework's scope